# Sort multidimensional array from z to a on value in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to sort a multidimensional array from z to a.
I can already sort it from a to z with this function:

```
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
                $sorter=array();
                $ret=array();
                reset($array);
                foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
                    $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
                }
                asort($sorter);
                foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
                    $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
                }
                $array=$ret;
            }
```

But how do i reverse it?

Comment: One way would be `usort`

Comment: Please review the **Related** section to the bottom right of this page

Comment: can you add a simple input and expected result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  `rsort` for reverse sorting

```
foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
    $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
}
rsort($sorter);
foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
    $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't wish to change your sorting function ...
you could use the [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) to reverse it at the end.

This is a example how to use it recursively for multidimensional array:

```
function Reverse_Array($array) 
{    $index = 0; 
    foreach ($array as $subarray) 
    {    if (is_array($subarray)) 
        {    $subarray = array_reverse($subarray); 
            $arr = Reverse_Array($subarray); 
            $array[$index] = $arr; 
        } 
        else {$array[$index] = $subarray;} 
        $index++; 
    } 
    return $array; 
}
```